# How to know if an admin removed a Telegram bot from group?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I encounter with a problem in programming of a Telegram bot via Python!
The problem is that if I add the bot to a group which is not super group I can successfully detect that the bot is added in that group via calling `getUpdate` method but if admin of that group decides to remove the bot I can't detect removing process because `getUpdate` doesn't consider removing process!
If the group will be a super group there won't be any problems at all!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`getChatMember`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) with the bots ID as the user ID.